# Ajax to submit form, and retrieve success/error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery with Ajax to submit a form to a PHP script.

The user will input their details, click a submit button, the PHP script will run and will have either performed the desired action or failed.

At this point I would want to display a success or error message based on the type of error.

```
<script>
$( "#contact-form" ).submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/contact-us.php",
        type: "post",
        data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
        success:function(data) {
         alert(data);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
        }   
    }); 
});
</script>
```

So in my jQuery above, when the form is submitted, it prevents the default `action="path to script.php"` then performs the submit. I've done this in case users have Javascript disabled, so at least the base functionality will be there.

PHP

```
<?php                  
    if(isset($_POST['contact']) && !empty($_POST['contact'])){

            $link = new mysqli("example", "example", "example", "example");

            if($link->connect_errno > 0) {
                die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
            }

            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $website = $_POST['website'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO contact (name, email, website, subject, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $name, $email, $website, $subject, $message);

            if($stmt->execute()){

                $rtn = "Success";

                echo json_encode($rtn);

                } else {

                $rtn = "Failed";

                echo json_encode($rtn);

            }                              
            $stmt->close();
            $link->close();
}
```

However, in this example, an alert box appears empty. No errors in firebug or Apache logs.

Is it possible to: when I perform an submit using Ajax, I can recieve an `echo "Text from error or success box";` which I can then put into a bootstrap alert?

The code I'm writing is new, so adapting to new libraries is something I would consider. This is purely for UI enhancement to show error or success messages, if the user has javascript disabled then the form default action wouldn't be prevented - they just wouldn't see a success or error message.

Something I have seen is ["Javascript promises"](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) I don't mind using Javascript if this is better in terms of useability, as I don't want to freeze the browser when a submit takes place.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look something like this

I would pass back a standard form of success/error from PHP. So failure might look like this:

```
json_encode(['success'=>false]);
```

Then acting on this in Javascript would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/contact-us.php",
    type: "post",
    data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
    success:function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);

        if (data.success)
            alert('success!');
        else
            alert('got failure response from PHP');
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("failure");
    }   
});
```

Comment: I see, this is what I'm looking for. The only issue is, on the "data = JSON.parse(data);" I get an error in firebug which reads "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: Then it must be coming wrong from PHP. If you have an old version of PHP, you need to use this terminology instead: array("success"=>true); If still problems, console.log(data) before and after the parse and post it here.

Comment: Got it working in the end, bit of tweaking with a google recaptcha element. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can use try catch() in php

```
<?php
    // ...
    try{
       // your code
       $msg = 'Success';
       return json_encode($msg);
    }catch(Exception $e){
       $msg = 'Error';
       return json_encode($msg);           
    }
```

?>

Comment: in my PHP I have an if() statement to see if the insert took place, however even when it wasn't successful because there was an error in my apache error logs, the Ajax callback was still successful. How do I solve that?

Comment: Your ajax will return successful always if he can send a request to the php file, so you need to verify the errors in your php file and return the message according with the request state, can u put the code php here?

Comment: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/X1gEcz1E) For the success/error messages, I know I have to json_encode. However, how do I make the Ajax call determine the success or error from an echo from the PHP script?

Comment: The success's or error's functions, it's just if ajax complete the request or no, so you need to send an response from the php if get a error or not, so you do an "if" or a try catch for this, and in the success function in your ajax you take the returnval, who will have your error or success message